# Xamarin forms Media Gallery Plugin

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'am Using Media Gallery Plugin form picking up photos from gallery.
it was working fine but recently it crashes my app when using it.
i've used both of these implementations .

first one

```
 var result = await MediaGallery.PickAsync(2, MediaFileType.Image);

        if (result?.Files == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Files are null", Class_Name);
            return;
        }

        foreach (var media in result.Files)
        {
            var fileName = media.NameWithoutExtension;
            var contentType = media.ContentType;

            Debug.WriteLine($"File Name: {fileName}, Content Type: {contentType}", Class_Name);
        }
```

and the second

```
 var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        IMediaFile[] files = null;

        try
        {
            var request = new MediaPickRequest(4, MediaFileType.Image)
            {
                PresentationSourceBounds = System.Drawing.Rectangle.Empty,
                UseCreateChooser = true,
                Title = "Select 4 Images Maximum"
            };

            cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

            var results = await MediaGallery.PickAsync(request, cts.Token);
            files = results?.Files?.ToArray();
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
        {
            // handling a cancellation request
            Debug.WriteLine("OperationCanceledException msg: " + oce.Message, Class_Name);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // handling other exceptions
            Debug.WriteLine("General Exception msg: " + e.Message, Class_Name);
        }
        finally
        {
            cts.Dispose();
        }

        if (files == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Files are null ", Class_Name);
            return;
        }
       


        ImagesBytesList = new List<byte[]>();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {                
            var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
            byte[] imageBytes = imageToByteArray(stream);                
            ImagesBytesList.Add(imageBytes);                              
            file.Dispose();
        }
```

and am also getting these warnings from Visual studio
[image]

and i got this log from the visual studio output pane

```
[Timeline] Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:385293562 intent:Intent { act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER (has extras) }
[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7fe527dfc0 in tid 4396 (.realestatedemo), pid 4396 (.realestatedemo)
```

so i think it has something to do with the android .
note that am running the app on my xiaomi redmi note 7 API28.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you show us the exception details? Without it all we can do is speculate

Comment: I does not give me any exception and i've tried to wrap the whole Method calling with try and catch and i did not get anything

Comment: I had test your code on simulator with API 28 , 30 and physical device with API 30. It works well. Have you try it on another device?

Comment: Then why does it crash if there are no exceptions?